# Who brought the Bluegrass influence into the Grateful Dead?

Tags: country, influence

When *Workingman's Dead* was released, it was a 180 degree turn into Bluegrass.  how could they make such a jarring change like that so quickly?

Comment: I don't know if you can say "180 degree turn".  Maybe a 90 degree turn at best.  The Dead have always been steeped in Country, I think if you find any article or interview about their origins it's pretty clear.  Bluegrass is just another branch of Country.

Comment: Not at all a 180 degree turn. (See Robert FInk's answer.)

Comment: Bluegrass is not the right term.  Country or Old Time or Acoustic would be more correct.   Bluegrass is a unique technical speeded up branch of country music.  If you like, bluegrass is to country as speed metal is to rock-n-roll.

Answer (score 4):

Jerry Garcia started off as a banjo player, and one part of the roots of the Dead were in a jug band called Mother McCree's Uptown Jug Champions. So I would guess that Garcia knew his bluegrass pretty well even before the rock thing came along.

Answer (score 1):

It was through hanging out with David Crosby and CS&N. Workingman's Dead isn't bluegrass, it's 'wooden music' based on songs with three and four part harmonies.